# Get the user who is logged in to windows using ldap for SSO

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I want to get the username of the User who is logged in to windows using LDAP in php. So far I am able to connect to the active directory and get users in a group, what I need is to get the `samaccountname` or `userprincipalname`. First of, I am not sure if they are different, and which I need.

```
$ldap_bind = ldap_bind($ldap_con, $username, $ldap_password);
if ($ldap_bind) {
    $attributes = array("displayname", "mail", "samaccountname");
    $filter = "(CN=*)";
    $result = ldap_search($ldap_con, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attributes);
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_con, $result);
    var_dump($entries);
}
var_dump($ldap_bind);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Do you want to get the username of the account logged in to your PHP app?  Or do you want to get the username of the account logged in to the computer that your PHP app is running on?  Why not use the `$username` variable?

Comment: The account of the Windows machine that is accessing the php app

Comment: Is this a web site, or are users running a PHP script on their own computers?